# (Oracle)Using WITH clause in subquery

Tags: oracle, subquery

My goal is to union the result of two WITH clauses.
Code1 below which uses UNION works as expected. But if WITH clauses are used as code2, then it shows ORA-32034: unsupported use of WITH clause.
How to modify code2, to union the two results of WITH clauses?

code1

```
select * from 
( (select 1 from dual)
  union all
  (select 2 from dual)
);
```

code2

```
select * from 
( 
 (WITH TEMP AS ( select 1 from dual )  select * from TEMP)
  union all
  (WITH TEMP AS ( select 2 from dual )  select * from TEMP)
);
```

Comment: Define the CTEs before the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
WITH temp1 AS (SELECT 1 FROM dual),
     temp2 AS (SELECT 2 FROM dual)
SELECT * FROM
(
    (SELECT * FROM temp1) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT * FROM temp2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to modify code2, to union the two results of WITH clauses?

If you really need to use `WITH` twice separated then:

```
select * from ((WITH TEMP AS ( select 1 from dual )  select * from TEMP))
union all
SELECT * FROM ((WITH TEMP AS ( select 2 from dual )  select * from TEMP));
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dd5d484ee07259c294677932721fdf5f)**